# AngularJS Syntax Error on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I started my first steps with AngularJS and wanted to create a Bootstrap form with a loop but get an error, what did I wrong?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="newForm" novalidate ng-controller="newFormController">
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': newForm.{{field.name}}.$invalid && !newForm.{{field.name}}.$pristine}" ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="{{field.name}}" name="{{field.name}}" {{field.validation}} placeholder="{{field.placeholder}}" />
        <p ng-show="newForm.{{field.name}}.$invalid && !newForm.{{field.name}}.$pristine" class="help-block">{{field.error}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

the Error:

> Syntax Error: Token 'field.name' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{field.name}}] starting at [field.name}}].

occours on parsing:

```
ng-model="{{field.name}}"
```

controller:

```
function newFormController($scope) {
$scope.fields = [{
    name: 'Firstname',
    label: Label.Get('28076475'), //First Name
    placeholder: Label.Get('44175380'), //Enter First Name
    validation: 'required',
    error: 'Firstname is required.'
}, {
    name: 'Lastname',
    label: Label.Get('28076500'), //Last Name
    placeholder: Label.Get('44175365'), //Enter Last Name
    validation: 'required',
    error: 'Lastname is required.'
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with `ng-model.`

Just change

```
ng-model="{{field.name}}"
```

to

```
 ng-model="field.name"
```

Comment: why do I need to skip the brackets?

Comment: @JanS, As ngModel is angular directive you don't need string interpolation, same with `ngShow` and `ngClass`

Comment: {{--}} is generally used for data binding.Here your are just creating a model.

Comment: @Satpal but I want to dynamically generate a model

Comment: @JanS : You have not implemented "ng-controller".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is placing value of field.name as modal. Here is how you can do it- Use `newForm[field.name]` in place of `newForm.{{field.name}}` in ng-model and other ng directives.